# Thick axis with arrow heads

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

By applying `AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.05}` we can make the appearance of the axis with an arrow at the extremities as follow :

```
Plot[1/x^5, {x, -20, 20}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.05}], 
     ImagePadding -> None]
```

Now, I want to make the axis thick at the same time.

The solutions I found use an AxesStyle rule, but I don't know how to cumulate two rules simultaneously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Directive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Directive.html) to combine multiple styling directives.

```
Plot[1/x^5, {x, -20, 20}, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.05}]], 
 ImagePadding -> None]
```

[image: Directive]